# MATLab Bootstrap without for loop

Tags: matlab, statistics-bootstrap

yesterday I implemented my first bootstrap in MATLab. (and yes, I know, for loops are evil.):

```
%data is an mxn matrix where the data should be sampled per column but there 
can be a NaNs Elements
%from the array (a column of data) n values are sampled nReps times

function result = bootstrap_std(data, n, nReps,quantil)

result = zeros(1,size(data,2));

for i=1:size(data,2)
    bootstrap_data = zeros(n,nReps);
    values = find(~isnan(data(:,i)));
    if isempty(values)
       bootstrap_data(:,:) = NaN;
    else
        for k=1:nReps
            bootstrap_data(:,k) = datasample(data(values,i),n);
        end
    end

    stat = zeros(1,nReps);

    for k=1:nReps
        stat(k) = nanstd(bootstrap_data(:,k));
    end

    sort(stat);
    result(i) = quantile(stat,quantil);      
end
end
```

As one can see, this version works columnwise. The algorithm does what it should but is really slow when the data size increaes. My question is now: Is it possible to implement this logic without using for loops? My problem is here that I could not find a version of datasample which does the sampling columnwise. Or is there a better function to use?

I am happy for any hint or idea how I can speed up this implementation.

Thanks and best regards!

stephan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bottlenecks in your implementation are

1. The function spends a lot of time inside `nanstd` which is unnecessary since you exclude `NaN` values from your sample anyway.
2. There are a lot of functions that operate column-wise, but you spend time looping over the columns and calling them many times.
3. You make many calls to `datasample` which is a relatively slow function. It's much faster to create a random vector of indices using `randi` and use that instead.

Here's how I would write the function (actually I probably wouldn't put in this many comments, and I wouldn't use so many temp variables, but I'm doing it now so you can see what all the steps of the computation are).

```
function result = bootstrap_std_new(data, n, nRep, quantil)

    result = zeros(1, size(data,2));

    for i = 1:size(data,2)
        isbad = isnan(data(:,i));                   %// Vector of NaN values
        if all(isbad)
            result(i) = NaN;
        else
            data0 = data(~isbad, i);                %// Temp copy of this column for indexing
            index = randi(size(data0,1), n, nRep);  %// Create the indexing vector
            bootstrapdata = data0(index);           %// Sample the data
            stdevs = std(bootstrapdata);            %// Stdev of sampled data
            result(i) = quantile(stdevs, quantil);  %// Find the correct quantile
        end
    end

end
```

Here are some timings

```
>> data = randn(100,10);
>> data(randi(1000, 50, 1)) = NaN;
>> tic, bootstrap_std(data, 50, 1000, 0.5); toc
Elapsed time is 1.359529 seconds.
>> tic, bootstrap_std_new(data, 50, 1000, 0.5); toc
Elapsed time is 0.038558 seconds.
```

So this gives you about a 35x speedup.

Comment: Hello, I think nanstd will not solve the problem since I would include NaN Values in my datasample which is not wanted. Or am I missing something here? Thanks and best regards stephan

Comment: Ah, I think I see - you want to throw out all `NaN` values from each column so that you don't even sample them?

Comment: exactly. Although it is useless to use nanstd here. I think this was missleading.

Comment: Hello Chris, thanks for the edited version - I guess you are right about using datasample - i think this and the inner for loops are the main bottlenecks. One small remark: Your example is way to fast since there are no NaN values to be filtered. But even with the filtering the it is a 10x speedup. Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue seems to be that you may have varying numbers/positions of `NaN` in each column, so can't work on the full matrix unless you're okay with also sampling NaNs. However, some of the inner loops could be simplified.

```
for k=1:nReps
    bootstrap_data(:,k) = datasample(data(values,i),n);
end
```

Since you're sampling with replacement, you should be able to just do:

```
bootstrap_data = datasample(data(values,i), n*nReps);
bootstrap_data = reshape(bootstrap_data, [n nReps]);
```

Also `nanstd` can work on a full matrix so no need to loop:

```
stat = nanstd(bootstrap_data); % or nanstd(x,0,2) to change dimension
```

It would also be worth just looking over your code with `profile` to see where the bottlenecks are.

Comment: Hello @nkjt, thanks for your answer - the reshape function is nice, but as Chris pointed out datasample is really slow so the randi version is the better way to go. Best regards stephan

Comment: Yeah, his answer is better. :)